# Resource 'data.template_file.user_data' does not have attribute 'rendered'

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

**Terraform Version** : v0.11.8

**Use case**

Try to terminate the resources using terraform, got error while running output command.

**Code:**

```
output "frontend_rendered" {
  value = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
}
```

**Debug Output**

> module.test.output.test_rendered: Resource
>   'data.template_file.user_data' does not have attribute 'rendered' for
>   variable 'data.template_file.user_data.rendered'

**Expected Behavior**

Termination without any error.

**Additional Context**

This issue came after i upgraded terraform from v0.11.4 to v0.11.8 and i have also updated the aws provider to latest 1.33.0

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: How is your data resource `template_file.user_data` declared?

Comment: It seems good. Because i am using that `template_file` in `aws_launch_configuration` with same syntax that i am using while doing output.

Comment: I'm right at the moment using the exact same code in the exact same versions.

Comment: Please post a minimal code example that allows to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @StephenKing Any other terraform plugin is coming in picture while executing this code?

Comment: only the `template` plugin, which is however at 1.0.0 since ages.

Comment: I get a similar error with v0.11.8 (sorry for the formatting in a comment):

`data "template_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  template = "${ ...interpolated string that uses values from the ec2 resources in the next line (e.g. ip addresses etc)... }"
  depends_on = [ ...list of ec2 resources... ]
}

output "ansible_inventory" {
  value = "${data.template_file.ansible_inventory.rendered}"
}
`

When I do a destroy, I get an error:

`Resource 'data.template_file.ansible_inventory' does not have attribute 'rendered' for variable 'data.template_file.ansible_inventory.rendered'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i was able to find the solution.

After Terraform v0.11.4, **we shouldn't evaluate unused outputs during a full destroy operation.**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, how did this fix the error you were getting?