# Terraform template_file does not have attribute 'rendered' on destroy

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I get an error when running `terraform destroy` where I have an output that is the result of a `template_file` resource, whose contents depend on resources that are destroyed.

```
data "template_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  template = "${ ...interpolated string that uses values from the ec2 resources in the next line (e.g. ip addresses etc)... }"
  depends_on = [ ...list of ec2 resources... ]
}

output "ansible_inventory" {
  value = "${data.template_file.ansible_inventory.rendered}"
}
```

When I do a destroy, I get an error:

`Resource 'data.template_file.ansible_inventory' does not have attribute 'rendered' for variable 'data.template_file.ansible_inventory.rendered'`

Is there a workaround for this? This appears to be the same problem reported here: [Resource 'data.template_file.user_data' does not have attribute 'rendered'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035992/resource-data-template-file-user-data-does-not-have-attribute-rendered)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing can be done at this moment, it's a known bug in terraform. The issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18026 is still open and haven't been resolved yet. The only way to get the code working is by commenting every output statement while running destroy.

Comment: Thanks @ShivRajawat

Comment: @ShivRajawat - why not write that as the answer and get credit? :-)

Comment: Because I didn't provide any solution. I just told him that his problem is actually a problem. :D @KJH